# Which to use between RS256 and HS256 for ASP.NET web client?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt, auth0

I'm developing an ASP.Net Core web application and will be using Auth0 for user authentication.

I'm having a hard time figuring out if my JSON Web Token Signature Algorithm should be `RS256` or `HS256`.

From the information that I have found, I still can't make heads or tails of it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though both algorithms make use of SHA-256, they are fundamentally different:

- `RS256` (RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 using SHA-256) relies on generating a digital signature with a specific **private key**.
- `HS256` (HMAC using SHA-256) relies on a **shared secret** plus the cryptographic hash function (SHA-256) to generate a message authentication code (MAC).

Validating tokens issued with each of the previous algorithms implies that for `RS256` the entity doing the validation knows the public key associated with the private key used for signing, while for `HS256` it implies that the entity knows the shared secret.

**Choosing between one versus the other is then usually motivated by the characteristics of the applications that will validate the issued tokens.**

If you want to validate a token on a browser-based application, the use of `HS256` is automatically ruled out because that would imply you would have to include the shared secret in a place anyone would have access, making it completely useless because now anyone with access to the code could issue their own signed tokens.

In conclusion, **if token validation is done on a controlled environment (server-side) you may go with `HS256`** because it's simpler to get started. However, **if token validation is done on hostile environment you need to go with an algorithm based on asymmetric cryptography; in this case that would be `RS256`**.

Comment: wait, "If you want to validate a token on a browser-based application, the use of HS256 is automatically ruled out" - why do you suspect the client code would need to know the secret? As far as I understand, the client would only append the token to every request to the API, and the token is returned to the client by Auth0 after logging in.

Comment: The keyword on that phrase is **validate**; if you want to validate a token in a browser-based application then very likely that the validation logic is client-side. A scenario where the client only relays a token would imply the client would **not** be validating it so it would not be in scope of the condition I mentioned. For example, an ID token is meant to be validated by the client application (which can be a browser-based application) while an access token is only relayed by the client to a resource server.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this @João Angelo! Now I get it, "validate" was indeed the crux :)